# color string resource for xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-resources

```
<string name="some_text">this is <font fgcolor="#ffff0000">red</font></string>
```

or

```
<string name="some_text">this is <font color="#ffff0000">red</font></string>
```

is not doing it.

I need to call the string in an xml TextView. How do I get it to work? No I don't want to use a horizontal LinearLayout with a bunch of TextViews.

Comment: you can't do this. instead of you can set `TextView` text like `textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<i><small><font color=\"#c5c5c5\">" + "This is demo: " + "</font></small></i>" + "<font color=\"#47a842\">" + "This is demo:" + "</font>"));`

Comment: use (in code): **myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("this is <font color="#ffff0000">red</font>"));** You can even get your string from strings.xml

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. instead of you can set `TextView` text as `HTML` like

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("this is<font color=\"##ffff0000\">red</font>"));
```

Go to this for more `HTML` tag support information :[html-tags-supported-by-textview](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

Answer (score 0):

TextView doesn't support entering HTML text directly, though some of the other answers seem to show you how to get a `Html` object from the String.  If you want to format the text within a TextView you need to use `Spannable` instances to format the sections of text to have different colours, fonts etc.  This is only good if you don't already have your text in HTML though, of course.